# Break Camel Case function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, camelcasing

I have been attempting to solve this codewars problem for a while in JavaScript:

"Complete the solution so that the function will break up camel casing, using a space between words. Example:"

```
"camelCasing"  =>  "camel Casing"

"identifier"   =>  "identifier"

""             =>  ""
```

I have it almost all the way, but for some reason my code is selecting the wrong space to add a blank space.
I'm hoping someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

```js
function solution(string) {
  let splitStr = string.split("");
  let newStr = string.split("");
  let capStr = string.toUpperCase().split("");
  for (i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    if (splitStr[i] === capStr[i]) {
      newStr.splice(i, 0, ' ');
    }
  }
  return newStr.join("");
}

console.log('camelCasing: ', solution('camelCasing'));
console.log('camelCasingTest: ', solution('camelCasingTest'));
```

Comment: This would be a lot simpler with `map()`.

Comment: Would love for you to show me as I am still trying to figure out how to use map().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first insertion into `newStr` will be at the correct spot, but after that insertion of the space, the letters that follow it in `newStr` will be at an increased index. This means that when the next capital is found at `i` in `splitStr` (which did not change), the insertion into `newStr` (which *did* change) should really be at `i+1`.

A solution is to make your loop iterate from end to start:

```js
function solution(string) {
  let splitStr = string.split("");
  let newStr = string.split("");
  let capStr = string.toUpperCase().split("");
  for (i = splitStr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (splitStr[i] === capStr[i]) {
      newStr.splice(i, 0, ' ');
    }
  }
  return newStr.join("");
}

console.log('camelCasing: ', solution('camelCasing'));
console.log('camelCasingTest: ', solution('camelCasingTest'));
```

This kind of problem is however much easier solved with a regular expression:

```js
function solution(string) {
  return string.replace(/[A-Z]/g, " $&");
}

console.log('camelCasing: ', solution('camelCasing'));
console.log('camelCasingTest: ', solution('camelCasingTest'));
```

Explanation of the regular expression:

- `[A-Z]` a capital letter from the Latin alphabet.
- `$&` backreference to the matched letter, used in the replacement.
- `g` global flag so all matches are replaced.

Comment: Your regular expression solution warrants some explanation. Many (even experienced) developers don't know (or have forgotten) how to decode that cryptic syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Here could be a solution with a simple loop and some if conditions

```
const breakCamelCase = (word) => {
  let result = "";
  // loop on letter
  for (let letter of word) {
    // if letter is uppercase and not the first letter of the word add a space followed by the letter
    if (letter == letter.toUpperCase() && result) {
      result += ` ${letter}`;
    } else { // else just add the letter
      result += letter;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I really like this answer as well. Very elegant and that is why I am practicing to be able to write loops like this. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function solution(string) {
  let splitStr = string.split("");
  let newStr = "";
  splitStr.forEach(e =>{
      if(e === e.toUpperCase()) newStr +=" "+e;
      else newStr += e;
  });
  return newStr;
}

console.log(solution('camelCasing'));//success = "camel Casing"
console.log(solution('camelCasingTest'));
```